# Pandas Profiling error within google colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, data-analysis

I'm trying to use `Pandas_Profiling.ProfilingReport` within my Google Colab notebook. This is my code:

```
 import pandas_profiling
 profile = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
```

and get that error:

```
" concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes' "
```

Comment: Do you mind to add pd.__version__ and pandas_profiling_version?

Answer (score 6):

Okha I have also gone through this issue and somehow tried to resolve it, so let me answer this question

Steps :
Step 1 : Run this command

```
! pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip
```

Step 2 : Restart the kernel by typing

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```

Step 3 : Import the libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Step 4 : Import and read your csv file

```
df=pd.read_csv('path of csv file')
```

Step 5 : Define your profile report and save it in a HTML document

```
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="data set", html={'style' : {'full_width':True}})
profile.to_file(output_file="name of html file.html")
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me & I was able to get a nice report. Saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `join_axes` function is deprecated in pandas version installed in google colab. If you downgrade pandas library version you can use Pandas Profiling. Just use in your colab:

```py
! pip install pandas==0.25
```

Then restart the kernel!

However, you will not be able to use

```py
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report")
profile.to_widgets()
```

as Google Colab does not support `ipywidgets yet`. But if you just use

```py
profile
```

you will get a report